# Why is my MVC model binding failing on postback for this enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a model class that has a value for `SomeEnum`

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public SomeEnum MyChoice { get; set; }
}

public enum SomeEnum
{
    OptionOne, OptionTwo, OptionThree
}
```

I've got an editor template that renders a set of radio buttons for enums:

```
@model Enum
@{
    var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType) 
                   ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;

    var items = Model.SelectListItems(enumType);
}
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        <div class="form-check">
                // also tried ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName below
            @Html.RadioButton(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, 
                 item.Value, 
                 item.Value.Equals(Model.ToString()), 
                 new {id, @class = "form-check-input"})
            @Html.Label(item.Text, new {@for = @id, @class = "form-check-label"})
        </div>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
</div>
```

Which renders as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input id="guid1" name="MyChoice.MyChoice" checked="checked" 
               class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="OptionOne">
        <label for="guid1" class="form-check-label">Option One</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input id="guid2" name="MyChoice.MyChoice" 
               class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="OptionTwo">
        <label for="guid2" class="form-check-label">Option Two</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input id="guid3" name="MyChoice.MyChoice" 
               class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="OptionThree">
        <label for="guid3" class="form-check-label">Option Three</label>
    </div>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
          data-valmsg-for="MyChoice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that the `name` attribute is ALWAYS rendering "doubled up" as `MyChoice.MyChoice` vs `MyChoice` (same when using the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName`), but I cannot determine the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be replacing

```
@Html.RadioButton(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, 
      item.Value, 
      item.Value.Equals(Model.ToString()), 
      new {id, @class = "form-check-input"})
```

with:

```
@Html.RadioButton("", item.Value, 
      item.Value.Equals(Model.ToString()), 
      new {id, @class = "form-check-input"})
```

That's right: replacing the `name` property (described as "*The name of the form field and the ViewDataDictionary key that is used to look up the value*"). with **an empty string** causes the `name` attribute in the html to render correctly, e.g.:

```
<input id="guid1" class="form-check-input" name="MyChoice" type="radio" value="OptionOne">
```

... and the model binding works as expected, passing the selected value back to the form in the model *as an enum* on postback.  It would be nice if this were documented somewhere, or better yet, *not this way*, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Convert enumeration to a string :

```
    public class SomeModel
    {
        private SomeEnum _MyChoice { get; set; }
        public string MyChoice
        {
            get { return _MyChoice.ToString(); }
            set { _MyChoice = (SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(_MyChoice.GetType(), value); }
        }
    }

    public enum SomeEnum
    {
        OptionOne, OptionTwo, OptionThree
    }
```

Comment: The editor template generates a radio button for each value in the `enum`.  If I use a string in the model, I'm just going to get a textbox.

Comment: But is is looks for a string like "OptionThree"